# Webpack ES6 import of ngJsTree

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, jstree

Hello need to import ngJsTree with webpack on ES6.

After 
npm install ng-js-tree --save

I tried:

import jstree from 'ngJsTree';
or import * as jstree from 'ngJsTree';

but always get:
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'ngJsTree'

should i use require and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed it as `ng-js-tree`, then it will be available as `ng-js-tree`.

Therefore try importing as:

`import ngJsTree from 'ng-js-tree';`

Comment: Yes Travo thanks! This were the following imports

import 'jstree/dist/themes/default/style.min.css';
import jstree from 'jstree';
import 'ng-js-tree';

Also to make it work did change Webpack configuration to make JQuery accessible:

config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({'window.jQuery': 'jquery', jQuery: "jquery", $: "jquery" }),